# Strange variable in class

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm trying to understand Python's classes and for that I created this simple program:

```
class TestClass(object):
    b = 3

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        print '*** INIT ***'
        print self.a, TestClass.b
        print

    def set_all(self):
        self.a *= 2
        TestClass.b *= 2

    def print_all(self):
        print 'PrintAll'
        print self.a, TestClass.b
        print

def main():
    c = TestClass()

    c.a *= 10
    TestClass.b *= 10
    c.b *= 10
    print c.a, TestClass.b, c.b
    print

    c.print_all()

    c.set_all()
    print c.a, TestClass.b, c.b

    TestClass.b
    c.b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I already understood that var c.a is an instance var. Var TestClass.b is a class/static var.

My 1st question is what is var c.b?

The program shows that it is different than TestClass.b.

My 2nd question is when should I use class/static vars instead of instance vars?

Thanks,

JM

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-static-class-data-and-static-class-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, `c.b` is initially another name for `TestClass.b`, because no `b` attribute exists on the instance `c`. However, as soon as you do an assignment to it by that name (as you do with `c.b *= 10`), you create a new instance variable `b` on the `c` instance which shadows the class variable `b`. From then on `c.b` is unrelated to `TestClass.b` and works just like any other instance variable.

As to your second question, there are a few times where class variables are useful. Perhaps the most common is for class constants, which are not expected to change throughout the running of the program. Python doesn't have any easy way to actually prevent other users from reassigning them, but if you name them in `ALL_CAPITOLS` and document that they're intended to be constant anyone who messes with them deserves any bugs they cause. Putting the constants in the class means that you don't need to recalculate them over and over for each instance (or worse, for each call to a method).

Another use of class variables is for bookkeeping, such as counting the number of objects of a class that have been created. This can be useful if each instance needs a unique ID number, just copy the current count into an instance variable! Other situations come up when you want to have only a limited number of instances (often just a single one, as a Singleton). You can store that instance in a class variable and return it from `__new__`, to prevent other instances from being created.

Some programmers like to use class variables as default values for instance variables that may be created later to shadow them (as in question 1). While this isn't forbidden by Python's language design, I tend not to like this style of code as it can be confusing to see a method refer to something that looks like an instance variable which doesn't exist yet. It can also get badly broken if you use mutable objects as the class variable defaults. I think it's better to stick with instance variables from the start, assigning them default values as necessary in `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, static variables are used to contain some general information about the class. For a simple example, let us say that you have a Student class which holds the info about the students in some class. You use an instance variable "marks", to keep track of object specific data. i.e. Marks of each student.

Whereas, if you want to keep track of the number of students you have, a static variable comes in handy here. So, the static variable can be increased whenever an object is created, and `Student.count` will give you the number of objects created.

Hope this helps...

As for your first question, I don't think TestClass.b is different from c.b. This is what I tried:

```
>>> class A:
...    b = 3
...    def __init__(self):
...        self.a = 1
...        A.b += 1
...        print self.a,A.b
...
>>> c = A()
1 4
>>> c.b
4
>>> d = A()
1 5
>>> d.b
5
>>> c.b
5
```